# Package withr is not available (R version 4.0.2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, installation, package

Today I downloaded R version 4.0.2 and suddenly have not been able to install ggplot2. The package withr is missing but when trying to install withr, devtools or anything else, it can't access the URL.

When copying the URL or saving the package on my computer and installing it using

install.packages("/PATH/to/package/withr_2.3.0.tar.gz")

It gives me the error

Warning in install.packages :

package '/Users/vera/Documents/R packages/withr_2.2.0.tar.gz' is not available (for R version 4.0.2)

Has anyone experienced this before? I've searched everywhere, updated my laptop (MacOS Catalina 10.15.6) but to no avail so far

Comment: Maybe check your internet connection? Firewall? Antivirus?

Comment: See this question from a little earlier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64050756/getting-an-error-installing-r-package-withr-as-a-dependency-for-ggplot2-how